# Returning a child class as their abstract parent class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, return, abstract

I am writting a console program in C++. Let's say I have the abstract class `Animal`, from which the instantiable classes `Dog` and `Cat` inherit.

Then I want to create a `vector<Animal*>`, so that I can go through the whole list of animals I have created and use their virtual function `GetName()`, which is overloaded in the child classes. Until here everything ok.

Now, I have this function in `main()` called `createAnimal()`. I want to make it in such a way that it can return a pointer (or reference) to the parent class, no matter if a `Dog` or `Cat` was created. So I wanted to make it like `Animal* createAnimal()`, but then an error appears telling me ***'Animal': cannot instantiate abstract class***. How can I return (in any way, pointer, reference) a child class as their abstract parent class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show `Animal* createAnimal()`?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. The idea is that, depending of the user input or an argument passed to it, there will be a switch case where an object of different type will be created (Dog or Cat) and then passed as the parent class.

Comment: The thing is I don't even know which return type it's supposed to have, but I want to send whatever object was created as the parent class, because it doesn't matter their real type for the use that I am going to give to them.

Comment: Sounds like somewhere you have something that looks like `Animal a;` You can have pointers to `Animal` (`Animal *a;`) and references to `Animal` (`Animal *a = myDog;`), but not a stand-alone `Animal` so long as it contains pure virtual functions (`virtual const char * GetName() = 0;`). Quick example: https://ideone.com/NiqtkP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is called [an object factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), but the error message you get means that either you've implemented the function improperly (something like `new Animal`, while you should never instantiate the abstract base class itself, only its children), or you're using the result improperly (like `Animal animal = createAnimal()`?)

So, is your code like this?

```
Animal *CreateAnimal(int type) {
    if(type == 1) return new Cat;
}

std::vector<Animal *> animalVector;

animalVector.push_back(CreateAnimal(1));
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am trying to achieve! Thanks for introducing me to the concept. What I am trying to do is `Animal* CreateAnimal(int type){ }`, inside of it a `return new Cat();`, and the function call is done like `animalVector.push_back(CreateAnimal(1));`, where `vector<Animal*> animalVector;`. Would that be the correct approach?

Comment: The lines you've quoted — yes, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal *cat = new Cat();
Animal *dog = new Dog();
```

Where the classes Cat and Dog are the children of the Animal class

```
class Cat : public Animal{
}
```

the Animal class should have the getName as an pure virtual function

```
 Class Animal {
 ...
 virtual std::string   getName() = 0;
 ...
 }
```

then you can manage your Cat and Dog class as an Animal class and call the getName member function, don't forget to override this function in Cat.cpp and Dog.cpp

I advise you to read some documentation about interface classes (classes which got only pure virtuals functions)

Comment: Hey @VK_, thanks for your answer but my problem is actually on how to return the objects as their parent class.